# GraphQL resolving based on "sister" fields results

Tags: graphql, apollo

Given a simple schema:

```
type Feed {
  posts:[Post]
  authors:[Author]
}
type Post {
  title:String
  authorId:String
  author:Author
}
type Author {
  id:String
  name:String
  ...
}
```

A consuming app can go ahead and request a feed of posts and their authors in two different ways:
1) the "normal" way to list authors:

```
Feed { posts { title, author { name } } }
```

2) a way so the app does it's own indexing of authors and therefore limits the response body size (since only unique authors are responded with their details).

```
Feed { posts { title, authorId } authors {id, name} }
```

This however poses a problem in resolving the query/authors since the list of required author id's is only known after resolving the posts, thus requiring the resolve of authors to wait until posts are resolved.

In short: a field needs to be able to wait on the resolving of a "sister" field, prior to be able to resolve itself.

One way of doing it is to create an event emitter, shared through the request context. And this does do the trick, however...
**I was wondering if there is a better / more elegant solution?**

FYI: the above example is simplified, in my use-case there are multiple fields holding relations to "entities", making the case for an "indexed approach" a lot more efficient.

```
type RelationType1 { entityId }
type RelationType2 { entityId, owningEntityId }
type RelationType3 { entityId, owningEntityId, representedEntityId }
type Item { rel1:[RelationType1], rel2:[RelationType2], rel3:[RelationType3] ... }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is move the implementation up one level into the resolver of the feed:

```
type FeedRecord = {
  postId: string,
}

type PostRecord = {
  id: string,
  authorId: string,
  // ...
}

async function feed({ userId }, args, { loaders }) {
  const feeds: FeedRecord[] = await loaders.FeedByUserIdLoader.load(userId);
  const posts: PostRecord[] = await loaders.PostByIdLoader.loadMany(
    feed.map(feed => feed.postId)
  );

  return {
    posts,
    authorIds: posts.map(post => authorId)
  }
}
```

Now the whole feed field will only resolve when the posts are already loaded. In this case you wont do extra work since you need the posts to resolve the authors anyways and if the authors are not requested the map function is not expensive. When you have more fields on your feed type (e.g. hasUpdates) so that neither posts nor authors are queried this resolver can be problematic and you might want to use the forth resolver argument *resolveInfo* to check if you need to do the lookups.

Comment: I get what you are explaining and it is a valid alternative.
In both cases a check into the resolveInfo is indeed required to keep it performant. (no need to load authors at root if it is left out of the query).
The main difference between both approaches is where the results get loaded. In your example the root query does the resolving, whilst in the event emitter, the resolving stays within the field. The event emitter does seperate concerns (where posts are loaded) a bit better though and limits the db requests of authors (although that can be solved using a dataloader ofcourse)

Comment: Actually now that I think about it you can resolve the posts also in the authors field's resolver. If you use Dataloader there will be no extra work done. I just think that "impure" resolvers are very hard to reason about. Let me know if I should adopt the code or if you understand what I mean.

Comment: @Herku I know its been 3 years but could you help to put some code around this?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/gajus/graphql-lazyloader